# iScroll: dynamic scroll container / add content / add more container

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll

After I found a way to make iScroll to work on **dynamically** added scroll containers and/or changed content length inside of scroll containers I have problems with additional functions, for example

```
myScroll.scrollToElement(document.querySelector('#scroller li:nth-child(10)'))
```

Instead of work with fixed IDs I worked around to use dynamically added class names, starting with `<body onload="loaded()">` as in the oringinal samples, like so

```
function loaded () {
    var myScroll;
    var iscroller = $('.iscroller');
    iscroller.each(function(index){
        myScroll = new IScroll('.iscroller'+index, { mouseWheel: true, click: true });
    })
}
```

which works fine so far for the scrolling function itself. Each scroll container, which in html/php code got a `class="iscroller"` before, gets another unique class name `iscroller0` `...1` `...2` and so on, by its index.

It still works fine, when content is dynamically added, like more `<li>`, to a container, calling of `loaded()` after. Scrolling still works as expected.
But when I want to call a function like

```
myScroll.scrollToElement(document.querySelector('#scroller li:nth-child(10)'))
```

it applies only to the last container, which **seems logical** to me.
So I tried to play around with even dynamically created objects instead of `myScroll` like so:

```
function loaded () {
    var iscroller = $('.iscroller');
    iscroller.each(function(index){
        eval('var myScroll'+index+' = new IScroll(\'.iscroller'+index+'\', { mouseWheel: true, click: true });');
    })
,}
```

Scroll **still works** as usual in all containers, but now I expected to be able to call

```
myScroll2.scrollToElement(document.querySelector('.iscroller2 li:nth-child(10)'))
```

but I get a console error `ReferenceError: myScroll2 is not defined`.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution. The full working solution is in this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

<title>iScroll test</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1-10-2.js.php"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/iscroll_5.js.php"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function loaded () {
    var iscroller = $('.iscroller');
    iscroller.each(function(index){
        $(this).addClass('iscroller'+index);
        var ul = $(this).find('ul:eq(0)');
        for(var i=1; i < 10*(index+1); i++) ul.append('<li>Pretty Row '+i+'</li>');
    });
    iscroller_init ();
}

    function iscroller_init () {
        var iscroller = $('.iscroller');
        iscroller.each(function(index){
            eval('var myScroll'+index);
        });
        iscroller.each(function(index){
            eval('myScroll'+index+' = new IScroll(\'.iscroller'+index+'\', { mouseWheel: true, click: true });');
        });
    }

function click() {
    iscroller_init ();
    myScroll2.scrollToElement(document.querySelector('.iscroller2 li:last-child'), 1200, null, null, IScroll.utils.ease.elastic);
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

</script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/iscroll_base.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/iscroller.css" />

</head>
<body onload="loaded()">
    <div class="module">
        <div id="header">iScroll</div>
        <div id="left" class="iscroller">
            <div class="scroller">
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="center" class="iscroller">
            <div class="scroller">
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="right" class="iscroller">
            <div class="scroller">
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer"><a href="javascript:click()">scrollToLast</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Scroll function works, as does the call of `myScroll2.scrollToElement(document.querySelector('.iscroller2 li:nth-child(10)'))`, (yes I have 3 containers in the HTML, so indexes of 0, 1, and 2 are available).

Yet I do not understand *why* the following works...

```
function loaded () {
    var iscroller = $('.iscroller');
    iscroller.each(function(index){ /*var wird definiert*/
        $(this).addClass('iscroller'+index);
        eval('var myScroll'+index);
    });
    iscroller.each(function(index){ /*var wird einmalig gefüllt*/
        eval('myScroll'+index+' = new IScroll(\'.iscroller'+index+'\', { mouseWheel: true, click: true });');
    });
}
```

But this not
(scrolling works but still ReferenceError: myScroll2 is not defined)

```
function loaded () {
    var iscroller = $('.iscroller');
    iscroller.each(function(index){ /*var wird definiert UND einmalig gefüllt*/
        eval('var myScroll'+index);
        eval('myScroll'+index+' = new IScroll(\'.iscroller'+index+'\', { mouseWheel: true, click: true });');
    });
}
```

And this neither

```
function loaded () {
    var iscroller = $('.iscroller');
    iscroller.each(function(index){ /*var wird gleich definiert UND gefüllt*/
        eval('var myScroll'+index+' = new IScroll(\'.iscroller'+index+'\', { mouseWheel: true, click: true });');
    });
}
```

This is still not logical to me, so perhaps somebody could post another answer to explain what's happening.